# Replace each element from a list with another from a dictionary list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, list-comprehension

In short what I need to be done is for each element from a list get the respective value from a dictionary list and replace it
For instance... For the following input lists

```
list1 = ['gui', 'guigui', 'guiguigguuii']
list2 = ['gui', 'gui', 'gui', 'gui', 'gui', 'gui']
```

I should look for in those dictionaries list

```
dictlist1 = [{'gui': 'ya'}, {'guigui': 'lyub'}, {'guiguigguuii': 'htr'}]
dictlist2 = [{'gui': 'asdf'}]
```

and it should output

```
output1 = ['ya', 'lyub', 'htr']
output2 = ['asdf', 'asdf', 'asdf', 'asdf', 'asdf', 'asdf']
```

I have written a code... However it is not working for the second data sample

```
print(' '.join([item for sublist in [[value for key, value in d.items()] for d in lista] for item in sublist]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, sorry if it's a bit long but, I think using this template your could figure something out.

```
list1 = ['gui', 'guigui', 'guiguigguuii']
replace = [{'gui': 'ya'}, {'guigui': 'lyub'}, {'guiguigguuii': 'htr'}]
newList = []
#iterate through list1
for words in list1:
    count = 0
    #iterate through replaces dicts
    for dicts in replace:
        #Check if any word in list1 can be replaced
        if words == list(dicts.keys())[0]:newList.append(dicts[list(dicts.keys())[0]])
        count += 1
print(newList)
```

output

```
['ya', 'lyub', 'htr']
```

Comment: What is dcs.keys() in the 10th line?

Comment: my bad forgot to change it. For clarification it returns all the keys in ```replace.```